# How to execute global packages

Tags: aws-cdk, pnpm

I'm trying to start an AWS CDK Project using pnpm v8.0.0 as my package manager. Then, I've followed these steps:

- Installed aws-cdk@2.7.0 globally:  `pnpm install -g aws-cdk`
- Created a new directory: `mkdir my-dir && cd my-dir`
- Tried to execute the 'init' command: `pnpm exec cdk init app --language=typescript`

However, I've got the following pnpm error: `ERR_PNPM_RECURSIVE_EXEC_FIRST_FAIL  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '/home/user/my-dir')`

I've tried to workaround this by installing aws-cdk locally: `pnpm init && pnpm install -D aws-cdk` and then running the same `pnpm exec...` command and then I've got a aws-sdk error: `cdk init` cannot be run in a non-empty directory!

The [pnpm docs](https://pnpm.io/cli/exec) is clear about `exec`: Execute a shell command in **scope of a project**.

My question is: How use pnpm to execute global packages?

Answer (score 0):

I also thought that one should use `pnpm exec` to run a cli program installed with a globally installed package, but through testing, or trial and error, it turned out that you can just run the cli program you installed *by itself*, without the `pnpm exec` prefix.

It turns out that when I installed pnpm with my package manager, pnpm added to my `PATH` environment variable the path of a directory where it puts wrapper scripts for these cli programs.

So, to run the aws-cdk cli, just run: `cdk`

---

I should mention that my pnpm version is `8.12.1` (which is the latest [release](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/releases/tag/v8.12.1) as of today), and I installed it with pacman, the package manager for the Arch Linux distro, which I use on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

I found this out AFTER I solved the problem by creating an alias for the `pnpm exec` command, to run commands globally:

```bash
pnpm-global-exec() {
    ln -s "$HOME/.config/pnpm/package.json" "./package.json" && pnpm exec "$@"
    if [ -L "./package.json" ]; then
        unlink "./package.json"
    fi
}
```

This alias can be used after adding the above shell function to your .bashrc or .zshrc, and creating a placeholder package.json in `$HOME/.config/pnpm`, with `pnpm init`, then you can use this alias like so: `pnpm-global-exec cdk`. but this is not necessary now, since it appears that pnpm supports installing cli programs globally when installing a npm package globally (with `pnpm add -g <package_name>`).